# Generating correlated numbers from independent distributions

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to simulate this scenario: 10 different algorithms are solving a number of problems. All 10 are run on each problem instance, which means if a particular problem instance is hard, I expect all algorithms to perform quite bad and vice versa.

Now, to simulate this, I created 10 different normal distributions from which I draw random numbers. These numbers represent the algorithms performance for some problem instance; however, since the distributions are independent, I'm not capturing the effect of the problem instance on the drawn numbers. Any idea how I can do this (i.e. correlated the random numbers that are drawn)?

Regards,

Comment: Could this relate to Copula? It is uncorrelated distributions, but with dependent structures. I am not sure whether the question is correct, because statistically independent means uncorrelated, but uncorrelation doesn't mean independent. The question maybe another way around.

Comment: I don't think I quite follow you

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what's "best" here, but a couple of approaches are thinkable.  One is to draw a random number representing problem difficulty.  (If you wanted, you could have additional values, for example, that index the quality of the algorithm.)  Then you sum these values.  For instance, in R:

```r
nProbs           = 1000     # the number of problems
nAlgs            =   10     # the number of algorithms
sigma_easiness   =    5     # the SD of the distribution of how easy the problems are

     # algorithms differ in quality:
algorithms        = seq(from=-2, to=2, length.out=nAlgs)        

prob_easiness     = rnorm(nProbs, mean=0, sd=sigma_difficulty)
values            = rep(prob_difficulty, each=nAlgs) + algorithms 
resid_variability = rnorm(nProbs*nAlgs)
performance       = matrix(data=(values+resid_variability), ncol=10, byrow=T)

> mean(abs(cor(performance)))
[1] 0.9636438
```

More complex versions can also be done (say, with the variability of the algorithms differing, or some algorithms performing better or worse depending on problem difficulty, etc.).

Sidestepping all this, if you just want to generate correlated data from a multivariate normal distribution, the function [mvrnorm](http://127.0.0.1:35424/help/library/MASS/html/mvrnorm.html) from the MASS library in R will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not quite sure I follow the R algorithm, I'm not familiar with R's syntax... yet. If I understood correctly, you suggest adding a random number to the numbers drawn from the distributions? For example, adding a 5 to the randomly drawn numbers? Best means a lower value since I'm minimizing.

Comment: Not knowing R is unfortunate, since my answer is R intensive, & R is ideal for these kinds of simulations. Several things: minimizing vs. maximizing doesn't matter here; note, I changed the code, e.g., I switched problem_difficulty w/ problem_easiness so that the directionality is the same as algorithms. Here's the gist of my approach: think of a matrix w/ rows=problems & algs=columns, add a different rand # to the elements of each row--each row gets a different #, but every element in a given row gets the same #, that makes rows tend to rise & fall together.

Comment: For one, you are right, I should learn R fast. Second, thanks for the clarification, it is as I expected it to be. But, I did try that out before, but I think this approach won't work, here's why: To simulate the problem difficulty effect, the numbers should be drawn from the appropriate parts of the distributions, for example, a hard problem means that numbers should be drawn from parts near the upper tail of the distributions (e.g. for an algorithm who's mean performance is 10 and std. dev. is 1, a number like 14 would indicate a bad performance for that algorithm, assuming minimization).

Comment: The opposite holds for easy problems. If a value, like 5, is added to a number, like 7, drawn from the lower tail of the just mentioned distribution, the final result will be 12 which indicates that the problem is of above average difficulty; however,  if a number, like 15, is drawn from the lower tail of another dist. (i.e. another algorithm's performance dist.) with mean 30 and std. dev. of 5, and the same 5 is added to it, the result will be 20 which represents a below average difficulty.

Comment: Clearly, the first dist. represents a better algorithm, but in this case we got the opposite outcome. That's why I think that adding a random number will not simulate the proper difficulty.

Comment: @Jawad, draw your rand #'s from a standardized dist (i.e., mean=0) and then adjust after everything is done. Ie, don't add numbers like 4 or 5, add +4 or -2. In the code above, the dists of alg quality, problem easiness and residual variability are *all* centered on 0.  You can adjust the SD's of these dists to influence the resulting correlations, eg, the smaller the ratio of prob SD to resid SD, the lower the ave cor. Likewise, broadening the range of the algs will influence how reliably they are ordered by quality, & increasing nProbs smooths the results.

Comment: I think I miss understood something, if the algorithms' performance distributions follow a std. normal dist., then they are all the same and adding random numbers to random numbers drawn from the dist. will simulate the problem difficulty, but we will miss out on simulating individual performance differences between the algorithms (since they all have the same dist.)... or did I miss something?

Comment: The algorithms do not have the same dist.  You have a matrix of random numbers; to every row you add a random number (representing problem difficulty), to every column you add a number (representing algorithm quality).  Now, once again you have a matrix of elements, but where the elements = a rand # (unique to that element) + a rand # (unique to that row) + a # (unique to that column).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a multi-level or mixed model would be useful.  You have two sources of uncertainty: the alorithm and the problem.  You can write this as

$$t_{ij}=a_{i}+p_{j}+e_{ij}$$

Where a is algorithm p is problem and e is error or interaction between problem and algorithm and t is you target for the $ij$ problem-algorithm pair.  So you generate a problem effect, and a algorithm effect from their distributions (which is assigned by you), and an interaction effect.  I would recommend the interaction effect if you have "tailored" algorithm designed for specific problems (eg exploit sparsity).

Comment: Thanks, the model you suggested exactly fits what I'm looking at. While creating the algorithm effect and problem effect can be easily done by drawing random numbers from the corresponding dists., the interaction effect isn't. Would you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: You would also draw it from a distribution.  The purpose of the interaction is to allow the algorithm effect depend on the problem, rather than be constant for all problems.  If you're not sure what to use, perhaps using an empirical distribution from a few test runs would be useful.

Comment: +1. This appears to be the same as another solution proposed slightly earlier.  The two replies together give a good answer.  I am upvoting this one because it uses a universal language--mathematical notation--developed for communicating such ideas to *people* rather than a narrow specialized language (R) intended for instructing computers.  The R version is *one* solution out of many possible (and therefore makes a nice *illustration*) whereas the mathematical version given here is a *general* solution which is readily translated to *any* computing platform.

Comment: @whuber, all of that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Multivar will do what you want: http://mypage.iu.edu/~haguinis/mmr/